# Calling a bean within a bean when a javabean data source is setup in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a ReportObject class which has a University class within itself. Then I have a MainClass having a function which returns an arrayList of these ReportObjects. This whole setup is set as a java bean data source in iReport and I am able to read all the field correctly.

[image]

But when I try to use fields within the university class (address and universityName) I get the following error:

Error filling print... Error retrieving field value from bean : address 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean : address      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getBeanProperty(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:123)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getFieldValue(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:96)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource.getFieldValue(JRBeanCollectionDataSource.java:109)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setOldValues(JRFillDataset.java:1358)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1259)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1235)

In my report I have imported fields address,universityName, studentName and gpa and I am using them in details section of the report as $F{universityName}, $F{address}.

Note: I tried just importing the university object and then using dot notation to get address and universityName but that also doesn't work.
When I execute report with just studentName and gpa it works perfectly fine, so the issue lies in accessing bean attributes of a bean which is in a 'has-a' relationship with another bean.

Comment: Can you show me the setup for this, like when I am trying to add a java bean source it is throwing error like classnotfound and check you classpath and try.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I have figured out the solution:
I should be using an expression like this : ((tutorial.ireport.University)$F{university}).getAddress() to make things work.

Comment: infact there is no need to case as well ...we can simply have ($F{university}).getAddress()